# My PHP foreach code is not working properly

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I found that in PHP I can use two types of foreach.

Here is the code:

```
$p2 = array('copier' => "Copier & Multipurpose",  
    'inkjet' => "Inkjet Printer",            
    'laser' => "Laser Printer",              
    'photo' => "Photographic Paper");

echo "p2 element: " . $p2['inkjet'] . "<br>";

foreach ($p2 as $item => $desc)          
{                                           
    echo "$item -> $desc <br />";
}

echo "<br />";

while (list($item, $desc) = each($p2))              
{
    echo "$item -> $desc <br />";
}
```

The second while loop does not iterate over the items.  Why?

Comment: What is the expected output, what are you getting? What have you done along your debugging phazes?

Comment: i have expected twice "copier -> Copier & Multipurpose 
inkjet -> Inkjet Printer 
laser -> Laser Printer 
photo -> Photographic Paper" but all i get is it just once...i dont know how to debug this...when i put there just one of foreach or while-each it´s working well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After the first `foreach()` is done, the internal "current position" indicator on the $p2 is at the END of the array. You need to `reset()` that pointers so the while() loop starts at the beginning again. e.g.

```
foreach($p2 as $item => $desc) {
    ....
}
reset($p2);  // <--you need this
while(list(...) = ...) {
 ...
}
```

`foreach()` does this reset for you implicitly each time you foreach() the array, so if your code had been the other way around (`while` loop then the `foreach`), you wouldn't have this problem.

Comment: Super! That works perfectly! :) Thanks, I can give you accepted answer in 9min, so i will come later and click it! thanks very much :)